# React: Button does not change its color after Material UI theme changed

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I wanted to see my contained primary button's color was slightly changed whenever the theme was changed, but I couldn't.

I saw it worked if I changed the button from the contained button to the text button by removing 'variant="contained"', but I really want to use the contained button

Is there any way to make it work?

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  // Because of <React.StrictMode>, <CssBaseline /> didn't work when theme was changed.
  // <React.StrictMode>
  //   <App/>
  // </React.StrictMode>,
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Button, Container } from '@material-ui/core';
import ChangeTheme from './components/ChangeTheme';
import { lightTheme, darkTheme } from './libs/Theme';
import { MuiThemeProvider, CssBaseline} from '@material-ui/core';


function App() {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState(darkTheme);

  const handleChangeTheme = (setDark) => {
    setDark === true ? setTheme(darkTheme) : setTheme(lightTheme);
  }

  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary">Hi</Button>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

libs/Theme.js

```
import { createMuiTheme, responsiveFontSizes } from '@material-ui/core';

export const lightTheme = responsiveFontSizes(
  createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
      type: 'light'
    }
  })
);

export const darkTheme = responsiveFontSizes(
  createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
      type: 'dark'
    }
  })
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the auto-generated dark theme provided by Material UI only changes specific colors from the palette. *It does **not** change the primary/secondary background (the `primary.main` or `secondary.main`) colors.*

Check [this page](https://material-ui.com/customization/palette/#dark-mode) out from their website, which lists the colors that are changed by the auto-generated dark theme. You will find there that text color is among the colors that are changed on theme change; that explains why you could see the change in your `variant="text"` button but not in the `variant="contained"` one.

Your best bet is to specify the changed colors manually for the dark theme in your theme declaration. Something like:

```
export const darkTheme = responsiveFontSizes(
  createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
      type: 'dark',
      primary: {
        main: "#000000" /*or whatever color you desire */
      }
    }
  })
);
```

Comment: Thank you, @Arjun for the answer. I am still confused though. Shouldn't button follow the color of palette.primary.dark not palette.primary.main if palette.type is 'dark'? If not, what is palette.primary.dark for?

Comment: @JasonKIM The `palette.primary.dark` does **not** specify the color to be used when the theme is dark. Actually, every `main` hue of a Material color has `light` and `dark` variants that can be used to show contrast in certain UI features: for example, you could use `main` color for the AppBar and the `dark` variant for the system's bar at the very top. Scroll to the _Primary Color_ section of this [page](https://material.io/design/color/the-color-system.html#color-theme-creation) from Material UI's website.

Comment: @JasonKIM In short, `light` and `dark` shades are completely irrelevant to theming. Material UI won't change primary and secondary `main` colors automatically. It only changes things like text color, paper background color. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much @Arjun. I am slowly getting it.

Comment: @JasonKIM If it solved your problem, please consider accepting this answer by clicking on the Tick mark below the votes. Thanks!